# Stuck at a silly loop in controller

Tags: angularjs

I have this function:

```
$scope.showCurrencyT = function(invCurrency){

    for (i=0; i<2; i++) { 
        console.log("i is " +i);

        if (parseInt($scope.pageInfo.currencies[i].currencyCode) === parseInt(invCurrency) ) {

           console.log('passed '+ i + ' ' + $scope.pageInfo.currencies[i].currencyCode )

           var symbol =  $scope.pageInfo.currencies[i].symbol
           console.log(symbol);

       } else { 
           console.log(i +" else")
           var symbol = invCurrency
       }

    }

    console.log("final symbol is " + symbol)

    return symbol

}
```

The '2' in loop can be `$scope.pageInfo.currencies.length` actually

The `$scope.pageInfo.currencies object` look like this:

```
 [  
   {  
      "_id":"59e5d2ad57acbb22bce66482",
      "name":"US Dollar",
      "nameInOriginalLanguage":"US Dollar",
      "nameStringId":"806c1313-a9f4-53bc-8f20-6897aae76d0a",
      "symbol":"USD",
      "currencyCode":"840",
      "__v":0
   },
   {  
      "_id":"59e5d2ec57acbb22bce66484",
      "name":"Turkish Lira",
      "nameInOriginalLanguage":"Türk Lirası",
      "nameStringId":"e072dece-4e18-d830-06b3-9e789a3b5240",
      "symbol":"TRY",
      "currencyCode":"949",
      "__v":0
   }
]
```

When I passing in view:

```
{{showCurrencyT("840")}}
```

I get in console:

> final symbol is 840

but when I pass it `{{showCurrencyT("949")}}`  I get final symbol is TRY

It should return USD for 840 and I don't understand what's going on!

Comment: Use a [break statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) to exit the loop when it finds the desired object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use for loop here, you can simply use array.find() method to find the exact matching value as follows,

```
$scope.showCurrencyT = function(invCurrency){
   var result = $scope.pageInfo.currencies.find(t=>t.currencyCode === invCurrency);
   return result.symbol;
}
```

Comment: thanks that works like a charm, I could use  return result.symbol - but I am dead curious, why my for loop approach didn't work?

Comment: probably because of the scope, you are declaring var inside the if and then using it outside, you need to debug and see. mark if the answer helped